# Maturity User Guide, Documentation and Ease-of-learning PHP-framework

Tags: php, documentation

I'm at the very start of a longtime running project with continual development. Because of that I'm hoping to make a good decision in which Framework will be right for this.

Previously I've worked with Codeigniter. A plusside is the huge community with a great User Guide. A few of the downsides are the backwards compatibility with PHP4 which holds it back and (therefor) the lack of OOP.

Because of that, I'm considering the use of a Framework like Kohana or Yii. I'm writing 'considering' because I'm not sure that the User Guide, Documentation is sufficient for us.

My question is not to start a blog-like upside / downside comparison. My question is whether or not you have experienced drawbacks from a more or less imcomplete User Guide, Documentation like Kohana or Yii.

Answer (score 3):

I've found kohana's documentation to be lacking. I chose Laravel instead for my company and I can't recommend it enough. It's well documented and I think you can get a team up to speed pretty quick with it.

Comment: Laravel or Symfony2 are the way to go nowadays.

Comment: Ok thanks, will consider Laravel. I'll leave the answer open for a while, hoping to get more response regarding for example Yii. +1 for sure ;)